# How to get all checked cheboxes from dynamic list

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular6

I have a dynamic list of checkboxes and I want to send only the checked to my request...
But I don't know how to do that...

Here is my list of checkboxes:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of places;  let i=index">
   <mat-checkbox class="example-margin secondary-text" [checked]="checkValue(p, i)" id="{{p}}">
      places
   </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Here is the checkvalue method. The `placesList` is the default and I use to check the checkboxes by default.

```
checkValue(item: any, index: any) {
   return this.placesList.some(e => e === item);
}
```

Comment: can you create the stackblitz for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let p of places; let i = index;">
   <mat-checkbox [checked]="item.checked" (change)="onChange($event, i, item)">
      {{item.label}}
   </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

And in your component add the `onChange` function:

```
onChange(event, index, item) {
   item.checked = !item.checked;
}
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularcheckbox)